# PDO execute variable which stores array

Tags: php, pdo

The $data variable stores an array containing a username and password, which need to be inserted in a certain table.

```
$data = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
foreach($data as $key => $value){
   $values = $values . "'" . $value . "'" . ",";
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO table(username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";
$query = $con->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($values);
```

How can I change this code in such a way that it will print the values of the $values variable into the execute function? E.g. 'Newuser','mysecretpass'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
$data = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
$sql = "INSERT INTO table(username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)";
$query = $con->prepare($sql);
foreach($data as $key => $value){
   $query->bindValue($key, $value);
   #echo 'key = '.$key.' | value = '.$value;
}
$query->execute();
```

The above binds each value to its placeholder, and if you want to print them you can.

Comment: @Pat4561 oh I know why , you need to use named placeholder , you see my edit `INSERT INTO table(username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this! Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of insert values.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table(username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";
$query = $con->prepare($sql);  
$query->execute(array($username, $password));
```

Comment: I already know that way, but the problem is that the array is already stored in the variable $values.

Comment: you mean, you want to assign it from this $data = array('username' => 'Newuser', 'password' => 'mysecretpass');

Answer (score 0):

You can [bind](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) the params like

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table(username, password) VALUES (:user, :pass)";
$query = $con->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':user', $data['username'] );
$query->bindParam(':pass', $data['password']);
$query->execute();
```